# Cocos2d for Android: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: android, dalvik, cocos2d-android

This is my first time using Cocos2d for android and I am trying to integrate it as a library from source code(I haven't tried the jar file yet). when trying to run the 
application he following error occurs:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/cocos2d/actions/interval/CCSpawn;
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:180)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:703)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:577)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:629)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:172)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:282)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:363)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:545)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1975)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:524)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:123)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1000)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:147)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:853)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:702)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:924)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1128)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-07-21 14:26:37 - TestingCocos] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

I recently upgraded to ADT20. so I hope this isn't some related problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem running the app, it's a problem building it. It looks like you've managed to include the same class in two different places (e.g. maybe both in the app and a library). The class's name is `org.cocos2d.actions.interval.CCSpawn`. `dx` doesn't have the prettiest error messages, but they're usually at least somewhat informative!